# Condition not satisfied in For loop using a List Collection

Tags: java, list, selenium, for-loop, collections

I'm trying to verify that a column in a table on a webpage displays the term 'Regular' in all of it's rows. Below is the code I’m trying to execute. when I run the code below in IntelliJ I get a failure of Condition not Satisfied. Changing the == to equals doesn't resolve the issue. What am I doing wrong here?

```
List‹WebElement› tdCollection = driver. findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='jsgrid-table']"))
for (WebElement element : tdCollection) {
element.getText()=="Regular"
}
```

Comment: Could you show the complete error message with stacktrace?

Comment: `element.getText()=="Regular"` doesn't make any sense as a standalone statement.

Comment: Is it a statement? A boolean expression.

Comment: You can use following check for string matching as `element.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Regular")`.

Answer (score 1):

If this xpath

```
//table[@class='jsgrid-table']
```

represent all the **Regular** term in rows, then the below **code** should work for you.

Also, you can put `OR` condition to have a check for `Regular` or `regular`.
Also, if you are using TestNG with integration to Selenium, you can use below assert.

```
List<WebElement> tdCollection = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='jsgrid-table']"));
for (WebElement element : tdCollection) {
        if (element.getText().equals("Regular") || element.getText().equals("regular")) {
            System.out.println("Regular or regular is present");
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm using Geb/Groovy so it didn't like the Assert line so I ended up changing it to a else fail. See below


List<WebElement> tdCollection = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='jsgrid-table']"));
for (WebElement element : tdCollection) {
        if (element.getText().equals("Regular") || element.getText().equals("regular")) {
            System.out.println("Regular or regular is present");
} else {
 false
}


Now when I run this I get the following results: 

Regular or regular is present

followed by Condition not satisfied.

I don't understand why.